# How to prevent uploading any file with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, upload

A hacker has found a way to upload a shell on our website :(

I have 3 question:

1. Is there a way to find out from where he uploads that shell?
2. How can I deny uploading (or creating) any file with htaccess?
3. Can a hacker upload a shell via a form without any "file" field?

Thanks

Comment: are you having cpanel or plesk on your server?

Comment: we have CPanel...